# Gnome3 system settings dialog crash

Tags: gnome

I am using gnome, and have recently upgraded it to version 3.10. however, now i am having several problems.

1. No wallpaper is shown on desktop. However, it is visible after super key is pressed (don't know how this regime is called - it is when one can drag windows between desctops etc. - overlay mode?)
2. System settings dialog does not launch.

How can i determine the reasons for that behaviour and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in:

```
/var/log/kern.log.*
/var/log/syslog.*
/var/log/apport.log
/var/log/Xorg.0.log 
.xsession-errors
```

If it is an issue with gnome then there will be some information in regards to `GDK-Warning:gnome-session:Some info about the problem`

There might be an issue with the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` configuration file.

Then do some searches about the warnings.